# Pass Parameter to Selector for Ajax Call onClick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, mongodb

Have a JQUERY AJAX call in a `$(document).ready(function()..)` that `loops` through MongoDB docs and adds HTML Divs to the page with a `.get`

Included in each Div is a `<button type='button' id='deleteItem' class='close' onClick='deleteThisItem(" + i + ")' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>"`

Each Div also has a form field, with a hidden value for returning the doc `_id` to then use in Express/Node.js to find and delete the correct doc (this does work in another app..)

```
"..<form name='theForm' id='theForm" + i + "'>
<input type='hidden' name='iD' id='iD' value='" + doc._id + "'>.."
```

Am looking to have the `button` delete the MongoDB doc onClick using an AJAX `.post`

```
      // handle DELETE (x) button clicks     
    $('#deleteItem').click(function(i) {

      number = i;
      alert(number);

      // make an ajax call
      $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $('#theForm' + number).serialize(),
        type: 'POST',
            url: "http://localhost:9999/delete",
            success: gotAllSuccess,
            error: gotAllFailure
        });

    });
```

Tried using a global variable (not ideal) `var number = 0;`, to pass the i parameter through a function outside of the `$(document).ready(function()..)` and have been researching callback techniques to callback the ajax, but nothing has done the trick..

```
function deleteThisItem(i)
{
  number = i;
  alert(number);

  //some callback to the Jquery in the ready doc?       
}
```

Comment: Use an anonymous function.

Comment: Yeh, that's what I was after, but am not sure what the proper format is for getting in or at the ajax call.. Recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have multiple records, don't use id for the button since id of an element must be unique, use class attribute to group them. Also there is no need to have an inline click handler

```
<button type='button' class='close deleteItem' data-id='" + i + "' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>
```

then use delegated event handler like

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(document).on('click', '.deleteItem', function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var number = $this.data('id');
        alert(number);

        // make an ajax call
        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $('#theForm' + number).serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            url: "http://localhost:9999/delete",
            success: gotAllSuccess,
            error: gotAllFailure
        });

    });
})
```